# Play Framework 2.7.x Compile Time DI Error

Tags: scala, playframework

Create project from https://github.com/playframework/play-socket.io/tree/master/samples/scala/chat and get compilation error

```
overriding method applicationLifecycle in trait MyApplication of type => play.api.inject.DefaultApplicationLifecycle;
 lazy value applicationLifecycle in class BuiltInComponentsFromContext of type play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle has incompatible type
```

Try with Play 2.6.23 and 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following [line](https://github.com/playframework/play-socket.io/blob/6ec41677e9b45ed0ea01692ed9d4c7906a37274b/samples/scala/chat/app/modules/MyApplicationLoader.scala#L23) from `MyApplication` should make it work:

```
override def applicationLifecycle: DefaultApplicationLifecycle
```

Test it with

1. `git clone https://github.com/playframework/play-socket.io.git`
2. `cd play-socket`
3. Remove the override from `play-socket.io/samples/scala/chat/app/modules/MyApplicationLoader.scala`
4. `sbt "scalaChat/run"` from the root project dir `play-socket/`
5. Hit http://localhost:9000/

Comment: I got the error Module [modules.MyApplicationLoader@6b1038e3] is not a Play module or a Guice module